# Why am I unable to set up the domain account for Splunk to receive data from a remote system via universal forwarder?

Tags: splunk

I am very new to splunk and trying to set up domain account, but with the custom options the installation rollbacks. I want to receive data from remote system by a universal forwarder. I have provided the same port number as the receiving port which is forward data configurations in remote system. What am I missing here? Can I do so with local system installation? 
same question is asked here ...

http://answers.splunk.com/answers/232340/why-am-i-unable-to-set-up-the-domain-account-for-s.html

but there is no answer..
Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service account must be entered as "**domain.name\username**" rather than just "**username**".

I experienced the same problem, having everything configured correctly for running the Universal Forwarder as a service account. However, I failed to enter the service account as "domain.name\username". Just specifying "username" does not work, either when running the installer interactively or silently.